# Can datatable stripes or selected shading have custom colors?

Tags: slds, datatable

We have a datatable that has striped shading (`slds-table_striped`) applied in HTML and selected shading (`slds-is-selected`) applied programmatically when the user clicks a row. However, both of these use the same color. For example, in this image, the third row is selected.

[image: Third row selected]

However, in this one, the second row is selected, but because it's stripped, there's no UI feedback that that's the case.

[image: Second row selected]

How can I apply a custom color to one of these, preferably the selected class?